# The vector coordinates of the exported PDF plot in Matlab are coarsely quantized

Tags: matlab, pdf, plot, eps

I have problems exporting to PDF and EPS from Matlab.  EPS does not work at all, it only saves an empty picture.  PDF works but the coordinates that specify the curves are coarsely quantized, resulting in a staircase looking curve, not a smooth one.

I.e. when I export as PDF, it is not using the data points that specify the lines, rather Matlab samples the curve and quantizes the samples to a very coarse grid.

How can one either:

1. save the curves according to the original data values, or
2. increase the quantization resolution?

Comment: For me what you want works right out of the box (both eps and pdf with the graphics in vectorized form). Something must be wrong with your Matlab. Please try on another computer.

Comment: It works perfect for me, can you specify the problem, do you try to code it or do you only use **save as** from the menubar?